# Find $c<0$ such that $\quad k+c>k^{-c},\quad j+c<j^{-c}$ for given $1<j<k$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For two given numbers $1<j<k$, I'd like to construct a negative number $c<0$ which satisfies

$$k+c>k^{-c},\quad j+c<j^{-c}$$
or equivalently

$$c+\log_k(c+k)>0, \quad c+\log_j(c+j)<0$$

And I want to express $c$ in a function of $j,k$. My guess is $c=-1+\frac 1{j+k}$.

Existence of such $c<0$ can be easily proved.

1. $f_p(x)=x+\log_p(x+p)\quad(p>1)$ always have a negative root $x_p$ between $(1-p,0)$ by intermediate theorem, which is unique because $f_p(x)$ is strictly increasing
2. $(\partial / \partial p) f_p(x)>0$ when $x>0$. so that $x_q<x_p$ as $p<q$

So any number $c\in(x_k,x_j)$ should satisfy $$c+\log_k(c+k)>0>c+\log_j(c+j)$$

But non of $x_p$ can be expressed in a closed form. So I can't simply use $(x_k+x_j)/2$.
$c=-1+\frac 1{j+k}$ is just a guess, nothing more. I've checked for ~$10^4$ and it worked. So it's promising to me so far.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please give me an explanation for your downvote. So that I can edit and revise my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $j$ close enough to $k$ then your choice for $c$ does not work.

For instance $j=2,k=3$ and so $c = \frac{-4}{5} =-0.8$

But $ k+c \not> k^{-c}$ since $k+c = 3-0.8 = 2.2$

And $k^{-c} = 3^{0.8}  \approx 2.408$